# Interface Builder NSStaticText value needs to be updated every time anything changes in dialog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I have a modal dialog thats building a string. The string is shown to the user, and the user presses checkboxes, radio boxes, etc to build the string. The string exists nowhere - I build it for display in -()builtString; from the configuration of the self.valuesDict.

I can easily wire up the checkboxes via bindings in IB: for example to the files owner (the controller) with self.valuesDict.checkbox1

Also I bound the display of the string to "self.builtString".

But every time any checkbox changes, I want to redisplay the string that's shown to the user.

If I abandon bindings, then I think I can use the [self willChangeValueForKey:@"builtString"], for each checkbox, etc, I think, but that is some messy looking code by the time I deal with them all.

So how do you tell a nstextfield in IB to update every time say self.valuesDict changes?

Thanks for any comments/suggestions.

--Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify dependencies between bindings. Just write a class method `+(NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingBuiltString` that returns a set with all key paths of properties `builtString` depends on. Then things bound to your string will also be updated when one of the other properties is changed. For more details and step-by-step instructions you can look at [this article](http://newwavedigitalmedia.com/?p=132).

Comment: Thanks - I don't think I would have found that easily. For others - the article is nice, you don't really need it, though. Just do as Sven says.

Comment: Yeah, this is kinda hard to find in the documentation. Everything I need that I have to use Google to find out how exactly this method needs to be called.